# Is storing an encrypted 2FA backup on Bitwarden (a password manager) a good idea?

Tags: password-management, account-security, multi-factor

I am at the moment using Bitwarden and a separate 2FA app.

I am trying to figure out a way to be able to securely recover my access to credentials and 2FA in case my phone/laptop/other electronic devices get stolen or destroyed and am not sure if what I am doing is good enough.

The app I am using for 2FA allows for encrypted backups with a password. I use Bitwarden to manage my passwords and it also requires a 2FA code from the app.

Now I have a backup of the 2FA app on Bitwarden, where the master passwords for both are long and different (consisting of letters only). I modified the 2FA recovery code for Bitwarden (so that only I know how to read it) and store it on a piece of paper in my wallet and some other places.

My plan is if all goes wrong to gain access to Bitwarden through the recovery code and then download and restore the backup of the 2FA app, in order to regain access to the other places.

Do you think that is secure enough?